# Youtube API v3 get comment missing library

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get video comments via Youtube API v3. I have followed the instructions given in the document and I have downloaded library in this page: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3#sample. I have added all the jar files in the library into my project but still I got somehow missing libraries. I got errors in these import lines:

```
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.V3CommentListResponse;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.V3CommentThreadListResponse;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
```

Which libraries should I add to my project and how can I get them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/pull/39

Fix: `V3CommentThreadListResponse` => `CommentThreadListResponse`

Fix: `V3CommentListResponse` => `CommentListResponse`